# Same functionality as Inner join on not linearly linkable tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Im currently designing a list in VBA (Access 2003) that uses several SQL queries in forms and subforms to fetch information from a centralized Database (tables are all linked via ODBCs in Access, Provider is 2010 SQL Native Client 10.1, SQL Server is in MSSQL)

Im currently working on a Form that fetches all fields from a singular Table, and then the Sum of a fields from a whole host of records in a secondary table.

My current SQL Query is this:

```
SELECT Chemikalien.*, (SELECT SUM(Bewegungen.Bewegung) FROM Bewegungen WHERE Bewegungen.Bestand_ID = Chemikalien.Bestand_ID AND Bewegungen.Typ = 5) As Umlaufmenge FROM Chemikalien
```

This is currently not working. It does not return an error, but it will not fetch anything from the Inner SQL Query (the Sum() part).

To be clear the intended behavior is:

- Fetch all fields from the table `Chemikalien`
- Fetch the Sum of all values from the Field `Bewegung` in the table `Bewegungen` where the field `Bestand_ID` in the table `Bewegungen` matches the field `Bestand_ID` in the table Chemikalien and the field `Type` in the table `Bewegungen` equals `5`

Comment: @yoyieyoyie for every row in the table chemikalien, there are potentially hundreds matching the Bestand_ID in Bewegungen.

Comment: `SELECT Chemikalien.*, Bewegungen.Bewegung`

`FROM   Chemikalien`
`INNER JOIN`
          `(SELECT SUM(Bewegung) as Bewegung`
                 `FROM Bewegungen WHERE Bewegungen.Typ = 5)`
`ON Bewegungen.Bestand_ID = Chemikalien.Bestand_ID `
`GROUP by Chemikalien.*,Bewegungen.Bewegung`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten SQL query. Try this one.

```
SELECT CH.*,
        T.Umlaufmenge
FROM Chemikalien AS CH
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT BE.bestand_id,
            SUM(BE.bewengung) as Umlaufmenge
    FROM Bewegungen AS BE
    WHERE BE.type = 5
    GROUP BY BE.bestand_id) AS T ON T.bestand_id = CH.bestand_id
```

Comment: In all my test cases sufficient data is present. There are entries in Bewegungen matching this criteria.

Comment: Can you add to your question example of current result table?

Comment: @fabulaspq I dont think that would be wise. The table has around 200 fields.

Comment: What value column umlaufmenge contain now in the result set? NULL?

Comment: Yep, NULL on all values.